# Clickable Links on a message box

Tags: javascript, php, html

I recently started working on a live application and I can’t seem to find a way to ensure users can send each other clickable links via the chat box

I applied different solutions from regenx code which didn’t work for me and other different codes, so if anyone can help I send a snippet of my code for you to assess

Comment: As per the [ask] guide, if you need help from the community please prepare a [mre] of your situation and add it to your question with an explanation of the issue. We also generally expect that you've made  good-faith attempt at solving it yourself before asking for free help, so please show your efforts too and show where you got stuck. You can [edit] your question. As you're new please also take the [tour]. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the tip and yes let me add my code